# What options do I have for running recurring events on a microsecond resolution from a kernel driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, timing

I want to create a simulation of an actual device on an x86 Linux Kernel. Part of this will involve simulating timings as close to possible as I can get. Based on some research it seems I will need at least microsecond resolution timing. I understand that on a non-realtime system it won't be possible to get perfect timing, but I don't perfect, just as close as I can get, perhaps with hacking around with thread scheduling / preemption options.

What I actually want to do is perform an action every interval, i.e. run a some code every *X*µs. I've been trying to research the best ways to do this from a Kernel driver as well as some research into whether it's possible to do this reasonably accurately from user mode (keeping the above paragraph in mind). One of the first things that caught my eye was the HPET timer, that is programmable to generate interrupts based on programmable comparators. Unfortunately, it seems on many chipsets it has been rather buggy in the past, and there's not much information on using it for anything that obtaining a timestamp or using it as the main clock source. The linux Kernel provides an HPET driver that in the past, seemed to provide both kernel and user mode interfaces, but seems only to provide a barely documented usermode interface in more recent kernel versions. I've also read about various other kernel functions and interfaces such as the hrtimer interface and the various `delay` functions, though I'm having a bit of trouble understanding them and if they are suited for my purpose.

Given my current use case, what are the best options I have running recurring events at a µs resolution from say a kernel driver? Obviously accuracy is probably my biggest criteria, but ease of use would be second.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's possible to achieve your accuracy in userspace -- `clock_nanosleep` is one ideal option, which has relative and absolute mode. Since `clock_nanosleep` is based on `hrtimer` in kernel mode, you may want to use `hrtimer` if you'd like to implement it in kernel space.

However, to make the timer work accurately, there're two **IMPORTENT** things worth mentioning.

1. You should set the `timerslack` of your process (either by writing nonzero value in ns to `/proc/self/timerslack_ns` or via `prctl(PR_SET_TIMERSLACK,...)`). This value is considered as the 'tolerance' of the timer.
2. The CPU power management also matters here. The CPU has many different **Cstates**, each of which has a different exit latency. So you need to configure your cpuidle module to not use Cstates other than `C0`, e.g. for an Intel CPU you could simply write `1` to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$c/cpuidle/state$s/disable` to disable state `$s` of CPU `$c`. Or just add `idle=poll` to your kernel options to let CPU keep active (in `C0`) while kernel idle. **NOTE** that this significantly influences the power of the computer and leads the cooling fans to make noise.

You can get a timer with delays under 10 microseconds if the two things mentioned above are configured correctly. There is a trade-off between latency and power consumption that you should made.